# Radical of the sum $=$ radical of the product

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

My question is:

Has it been proved/disproved or studied the following?

For every $k\geq 4$ there are $k$ pairwise relatively prime numbers $a_1,a_2,...,a_k$ all greater than $1$ such that  $$\text{rad}(a_1+a_2+...+a_k)=\text{rad}(a_1\cdot a_2\cdots a_k)$$

The radical of $n$ is the product of the distinct prime factors of $n$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $k$ is odd, then $1+1+\cdots+1+2+k=1\cdot1\cdots2\cdot k$, where there are $k-2$ ones on each side.

Comment: What about 2+2+2+3+3+6=18?

Comment: Not 18, but 30 works for $k=3$.  Gerhard "Working On Three Plus Two" Paseman, 2015.11.10

Comment: 2048 + 125 + 121 + 9 + 7 = 2310.  One might use a density/probabilistic argument to show existence for larger k. Gerhard  "But I'm Not Doing That" Paseman, 2015.11.10

Comment: @Jan-ChristophSchlage-Puchta the numbers you use are not pairwise realtively prime

Comment: I am having a hard time finding a solution with k= 3 a_i for which the radical is 105.  This might lead to asking for which squarefree n is a solution with n=rad(...) involving at most k terms possible?  Gerhard "Will Let Someone Else Ask" Paseman, 2015.11.12

Answer (score 2):

Let $k=2j$ be even, and choose $k$ or more distinct primes, whose product $P$ is the radical of $k$ pairwise coprime numbers to be chosen.

Case $P$ is odd:  Then the $2j$ numbers to be chosen are odd, and the sum is even, so $P$ is even, contradiction.

Case $P$ is even: Then, being pairwise coprime, one of the $2j$ numbers is even and the rest are odd, so the sum is odd, so $P$ is odd, contradiction.

So no such solutions for $k$ even.

You can investigate representations of odd squarefree numbers as a sum of powers or special multiples of their factors.  I do not know of any examples.  I suspect that the subject is a curiosity with few or no ties to other aspects of number theory, yet.

Gerhard "So Go And Make Some" Paseman, 2015.11.10

Comment: Or to paraphrase from dim memory: " But the only number that is both even and odd is infinity, so P is infinite, thus Alexander The Great did not exist and he had an infinite number of limbs." Gerhard "A Random Walk In Science" Paseman, 2015.11.10

Comment: Note that $P$ can also be the product of $k$ or fewer primes, if one or more instances of 1 are allowed.  Thus examples like Jan-Christoph's involving $k$ even must have noncoprime numbers for the $a_i$.  Gerhard "Start Looking To Generalize This" Paseman, 2015.11.10

Comment: What about the example given by Jan-Christoph Schlage-Puchta?

Comment: @StefanKohl, perhaps I spoke too briefly.  By "noncoprime" I mean at least two of the numbers a_i share a prime factor or more in common.  There is a better way of saying this, but it is longer.  In any case, the proof above shows that k even means no solution where all integers are coprime in pairs.  Jan-Christoph's example has at least two members which share a prime factor.  Gerhard "Didn't I Say This Already?" Paseman, 2015.11.10